# Determining the Lipschitz constants for this system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, normed-spaces

We consider the following system of ODE:

$$  u_1' = 4u_1 + 3u_2\\
    u_2' = 5u_1 - 6u_2 $$

I need to determine the Lipschitz constants for this system in the max norm $||.||_{\infty}$ and the $1$-norm $||.||_1.$

I understand that we're considering the vector valued function $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, F(u_1,u_2):= (4u_1 + 3u_2, 5u_1 - 6u_2),$ and we're supposed to find the Lipschitz constant for this $F$ in the max norm $||.||_{\infty}$ and the $1$-norm $||.||_1.$ But I'm a bit confused how to do that, or what theorems to use. Could you please help me out here? Perhaps at least point me to the right theorem? I think I need to consider the operator norm when we equip $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the max norm $||.||_{\infty}$ and the $1$-norm $||.||_1.$ Is that correct? But then, I'm having trouble finding the operator norms w.r.t. these two norms. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have a linear system. The Lipschitz constant is the (operator) norm of the Jacobian is the norm of the system matrix. In the case of the max norm on the vector space you get the row-sum norm for the matrix, and for the one-norm of the vector space you get the column-sum norm for the matrix. The first gives $L=11$, the second $L=9$.

---

On the operator norms associated to the cited vector norms:

- for the max norm
  $$
  \|Ax\|_\infty=\max_i\Bigl|\sum_j a_{ij}x_j\Bigr|\le\Bigl(\max_i\sum_j|a_{ij}|\Bigr)\|x\|_\infty=\|A\|_{op,\infty}\|x\|_\infty.
  $$
- and for the one norm
  $$
  \|Ax\|_1=\sum_i\Bigl|\sum_ja_{ij}x_j\Bigr|\le \sum_j\Bigl(\sum_i|a_{ij}|\Bigr)|x_j|\le \Bigl(\max_j\sum_i|a_{ij}|\Bigr)\sum_j|x_j|=\|A\|_{op,1}\|x\|_1
  $$
  In both cases vectors consisting of $0,\pm1$ can be constructed that realize the equality sign in every inequality.

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't follow the part: "In the case of the max norm on the vector space you get the row-sum norm for the matrix, and for the one-norm of the vector space you get the column-sum norm for the matrix. The first gives L=11, the second L=9". Could you be a bit more explicit and show the calculations please? Thanks!

Comment: These are standard examples for matrix norms defined as operator norms, the row-sum norm of $A$ is for instance $\max_i\sum_j|a_{ij}|$. There is not much to explain.

Comment: Thanks - but what I'm looking for is a proof of: "In the case of the max norm on the vector space you get the row-sum norm for the matrix as the operator norm, and for the one-norm of the vector space you get the column-sum norm for the matrix as the operator norm". Could you please cite a link  or prove it? TIA!